# Slack APP using Slash Command installed in workspace but not showing in Channels?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am new to Slack and was following a Youtube video to create a Slack App using Slash commands... I have successly created the App and installed it into my workspace. However it is not available in any of my Workspace Channels? Is there a step I am missing to make the command "/echo" available to invoke my function to my Channels?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the following:

1. Invite the slack app to your channel.
2. Ensure you have set the correct response `URL` in the slash command setup.
3. If you need this available for everyone in your workspace I'd suggest using the bot `OAUTH` token to initialize your slack application